# restheart date format issue

Tags: mongodb, url, restheart

I Have two data in the same file like

```
    {
      "_id": {
      "$oid": "57852a53"
      },
      "date": "2016-1-7"
    },
    {
      "_id": {
      "$oid": "57852a54"
        },
  "date": "2016-1-22
  }
```

if I querying  http://test:8081/xyz?filter={'date':{'$gte':'2016-1-22'}}
it showing both data

I think it's not an issue but I didn't find the solution yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are storing data as a string (not a proper one).
Ideally, Suggest you to change type to Date/long.

Example data:

```
{
  "_id": {
  "$oid": "57852a53"
  },
  "date": ISODate("2016-01-07T00:00:00Z")
},
{
  "_id": {
  "$oid": "57852a54"
    },
  "date": ISODate("2016-01-22T00:00:00Z")
}
```

If you want to persist your date a string, you can try storing in following format (note the **zeros** before single digit numbers) and your query should work fine.

```
{
  "_id": {
  "$oid": "57852a53"
  },
  "date": "2016-01-07"
},
{
  "_id": {
  "$oid": "57852a54"
    },
  "date": "2016-01-22"
}
```